# peer invalid error message with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm attempting to install swagger-ui into an existing project and I'm getting the following error messages:

```
Olivers-MacBook-Pro:incrementum oliverpike$ npm install --save-dev --save-exact swagger-ui@3.2.0
npm WARN deprecated create-react-class@15.5.2: create-react-class has known issues with Browserify before version 15.5.3. Please update create-react-class to 15.5.3 or a newer version.
npm WARN saveError Problems were encountered
npm WARN saveError Please correct and try again.
npm WARN saveError peer invalid: react@^0.14.8, required by react-addons-shallow-compare@0.14.8
npm WARN saveError peer invalid: react@^0.14.0, required by react-object-inspector@0.2.1
bitcoin-core-custom@1.0.1 /Volumes/github-image/bitcoin-core
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.6.1
└─┬ swagger-ui@3.2.0 
  ├─┬ brace@0.7.0 
  │ └── w3c-bl
 (rest snipped...)

npm WARN react-addons-shallow-compare@0.14.8 requires a peer of react@^0.14.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-object-inspector@0.2.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 but none was installed.
```

IOW, it sounds like react-addons-shallow-compare and react-object-inspector don't like the newer version of react (15.6.1). Are my only 2 options to downgrade the version of react in the project or install swagger_ui into a different directory where it can have its own dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with swagger-ui-dist (which doesn't have this problem) instead of swagger-ui.